# "data = opener.open()" stuck in a loop but "opener.open()" isn't

Tags: python, urllib2

I have a local WAMP server and come across this problem when I was trying to run this python code:

```
import urllib2
import time
h = urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel = 1)
request = urllib2.Request('http://127.0.0.1/test.html')
request.add_header('User-Agent','test/1.0')
opener = urllib2.build_opener(h)
t = time.clock()

for i in range(2):
    data = opener.open(request)
print 'it costs %fs' % (time.clock() - t)
```

result: `it costs 118.455130s`

But when I replace `data = opener.open(request)` with `opener.open(request)`, it seems normal.

result: `it costs 0.001970s`

I can repeat the result. Why does this happen?

Comment: Unable to reproduce the issue at my end. `data` or no `data`, both take about the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean:

```
data = opener.open(request).read()
```

Right?

Reading response body takes time according to its content size.

Comment: no, I mean adding the "data = " makes it running much longger, very odd problem. By the way I use Enthought Canopy python environment